# "Holes" in array when use es6 spread operator on string with emojis

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

Why when I try split string with emoji(s) using spread(...) operator I get "holes" in result array?

Example: 
`[...''] // -> ["", hole]`

Also more emojis creates more "holes": 
`[...''] // -> ["", "", hole, hole]`

Screenshot from Chrome v71.0.3578.98:

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried reproducing this on Firefox 64 and Safari 12 and I could not. It seems to be a Chrome specific behavior.

Comment: I think Chrome v71.0.3578.98 has problem, I tried with my Chrome and Safari and Firefox, it doesn't happen

Comment: Unable to replicate on Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @phuzi It worked for me on v70.x. After I updated, I could reproduce this.

Comment: Seems like an issue with the recent version of Chrome. JS considers '' to have length 2, due to how it handles Unicode. However ES6's Array.from() and the spread operator should handle this correctly as is the case with other browsers and the previous version of Chrome.

Comment: Yep, this is a bug in V8. We’ve already fixed it a while back, and the fix will propagate to a stable Chrome release soon.

Comment: The relevant V8 bug is [914409](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914409).

Answer (score 6):

Certainly this is a bug.

As a workaround, `Array.from()` works identically except it isn't buggy.

```
> s="\uD83C\uDF1F\u5FCD\u8005\u306E\u653B\u6483\uD83C\uDF1F"
> [...s]
(9) ["", "忍", "者", "の", "攻", "撃", "", hole, hole]
> Array.from(s)
(7) ["", "忍", "者", "の", "攻", "撃", ""]
```

It looks like the fix is in Chrome 72, but you could open a bug in Chromium and ask for it to be merged to 71.

The fix and test case are here: https://crrev.com/902d21dd661033427b56d5f93c12b12339bf55ab

(I believe "hole" is V8 telling you that some native code screwed up and failed to initialize the array properly, in contrast to "empty" which can be produced by ordinary javascript.)

Yep, V8 has definitely confused itself:

```
> a=[...'\u{1f4a9}']
(2) ["", hole]
> hole=a[1]
undefined
> hole
VM384:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: hole is not defined
```

Comment: phew...just updated Chrome and my problem went away...thanks!